# What test to test difference between two independent groups of (very) unequal size?

Tags: sample-size, large-data

My goal is to test the difference between two independent and non parametric samples of unequal size (3191 and 2209). One sample concerns questions and the other one responses and the data concerns occurrence counts of a certain word.

So the data looks like this:

a = [0,1,0,3,4,...,2,0] with length 3191

b = [0,0,3,0,2,...,1,2,3] with length 2209

What should I use to test whether there's a statistical difference between the two samples?

Comment: What do you want to test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want to know if the word occurs more often
in the question than in the answer.

Suppose data are as shown below:

```
table(a); mean(a); sd(a); length(a)
 a
   0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7 
 783 1128  744  366  119   38   10    3 
 [1] 1.397994   # sample mean
 [1] 1.190683   # sample standard deviation
 [1] 3191       # sample size

table(b); mean(b); sd(b); length(b)
b
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6 
588 772 541 224  60  18   6 
[1] 1.30919     # sample mean
[1] 1.124461    # sample SD
[1] 2209        # sample size
```

For such large samples it should be OK to use a Welch two-sample t test (even though the data are not normal), which shows a significant difference at the 1% level.
(There seems to be a slight difference in variability between `a` and `b`, but the Welch test does not assume equal variances.

```
t.test(a,b)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  a and b
t = 2.7851, df = 4915.9, p-value = 0.005371
alternative hypothesis: 
 true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.0262950 0.1513144
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 1.397994  1.309190
```

Another choice would be to use a two-sample Wilcoxon (rank sum) test, which shows a significant difference in locations at the
5% level.

```
wilcox.test(a,b)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  a and b
W = 3647200, p-value = 0.02346
alternative hypothesis: 
 true location shift is not equal to 0
```

If you are mainly interested in whether the proportions
of various integer counts is the same for the questions and
answers, then you might use a chi-squared test with six 'categories':
'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', and '5 or more'.

```
TBL = rbind(c(337,1128,744,366,119,51),
            c(588,772,341,224,60,34))
ch.out = chisq.test(TBL);  ch.out

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL
X-squared = 236.37, df = 5, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

The very low P-value indicates that the proportions are not
the same for the six categories. We can use `$`-notation to look at observed counts. (A chance to make sure the data are correctly entered.)

```
ch.out$obs
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]  337 1128  744  366  119   51
[2,]  588  772  341  224   60   34
```

Expected counts are computed according to the assumption that
proportions in the categories *are* consistent between `a` and `b`.

```
ch.out$exp
         [,1]      [,2]     [,3]     [,4]      [,5]    [,6]
[1,] 532.9817 1094.7733 625.1732 339.9559 103.13917 48.9767
[2,] 392.0183  805.2267 459.8268 250.0441  75.86083 36.0233
```

Looking at Pearson residuals can help to show cases in which
expected counts do not closely match observed counts and thus
to focus on the main differences between `a` and `b`. [The sum of the squared residuals is the chi-squared statistic.]

For example, the residuals with highest absolute values (above 2 in absolute value) occur
in categories '0' and '2' (columns labeled `[,1]` and `[,3]`). In category '0', `a` has many fewer than the expected number of counts; in category '2' `a` has many more that the expected number of counts. For sample`b` it is the reverse.

```
ch.out$res
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]       [,6]
[1,] -8.489057  1.004211  4.752415  1.412530  1.561759  0.2891116
[2,]  9.898342 -1.170922 -5.541373 -1.647027 -1.821030 -0.3371076
```